# Excel add-in saved on Dropbox - formula from add-in appearing with filepath

Tags: path, dropbox, add-in, shared

I would need some advice on the following problem. We have 1 shared add-in we all use for different excel sheets in my company (saved on a dropbox folder because we need to update it with different values regularly). When opening one excel sheet using the formulas from the modules of the add-in, those formulas appear with the filepath of the add-in (called CDM_v5.4.xlam), thus do not calculate anything. See below 1 example with the correct formula and the error appearing in all cells using formulas.

Correct formula : =fres_MNR([@type];[@kNADL])
Error with filepath : ='C:\Dropbox (CDM)\CDM Materials\Calculation programs\CDM_v5.4.xlam'!fres_MNR([@type];[@kNADL])

I digged in forum topics to find a solution. Is there a way to get rid of the problem without having to use a find & replace all the cells using those formumas (replacing filepath with "") or to use a macro to delete those filepath in any cell where it appears?

Thanks for any help,
G